# iOS to iOS device connection through IP - Address

Tags: ios, networking, ip, p2p

Can we connect two devices or multiple devices via IP Address?

I have already implemented connection using BT and wi-fi.

Comment: How do you think "connection using wi-Fi" works?

Comment: If you are asking about programatically look for socket communications in IOS.

Comment: @EmilyJ,Through Gamekit and MPC framework we can connect multiple devcies via BT and Wi-fi.

Comment: @RCBrand I know that I have to use Socket Communication .But Do u have any sample code for that Or how can I write that in Program???Please help .

Comment: I didn't work on IOS anytime before. Just that you asked for the socket communications I found this[link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7815634?messageID=7815634#7815634?messageID=7815634).

Comment: Try this library.  It is simple to use:  https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket